# Inherit color under a background

Tags: css, button, colors, background, background-color

I want to make dashed button that inherit the background color.
[Here what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxD67.png) (but I really want to be able to change the button color without changing the dash background.)
Here's the code I have :

```css
body {
  font-family:"Open Sans", sans-serif;
}
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.5em 0.8em;
  vertical-align: top;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
}
.btn.red {
  background-color:#dd2c2c;
  color:#f4f4f4;
}
.btn.blue {
  background-color:#2c84dd;
  color:#f4f4f4;
}
.btn.dash {
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(
    -45deg,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0),
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 10px,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 10px,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 20px),
    inherit;
 }
```

```html
<div class="btn dash red">Red Button</div>
<div class="btn dash blue">Blue Button</div>
```

With this code I can't see the dashed part. But if I change the "inherit" for a "real" value (like #dd2c2c) it works! How can I do something so it keep is original Background-Color value but with the dashed hover?

Answer (score 7):

Since `repeating-linear-gradient` creates an image, and is not a color, you can set it using `background-image`, and the `background-color` you defined in the 2nd class will take effect as well.

```css
body {
  font-family:"Open Sans", sans-serif;
}
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.5em 0.8em;
  vertical-align: top;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
}
.btn.red {
  background-color:#dd2c2c;
  color:#f4f4f4;
}
.btn.blue {
  background-color:#2c84dd;
  color:#f4f4f4;
}
.btn.dash {
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(
    -45deg,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0),
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 10px,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 10px,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 20px
  );
 }
```

```html
<div class="btn dash red">Red Button</div>
<div class="btn dash blue">Blue Button</div>
```

In your case it didn't work because this is not the correct format for a background:

```
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(
    -45deg,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0),
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 10px,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 10px,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 20px), /** remove the comma **/
    inherit
 }
```

This is the correct definition:

```
  background: inherit repeating-linear-gradient(
    -45deg,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0),
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 10px,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 10px,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 20px);
 }
```

However, in this case `background` is "stronger" the `background-color`, and `inherit` will replace the `background-color` you've defined. Since the parent doesn't have a `background-color`, it won't work as well.

Answer (score 0):

For future visits :

If your goal is to apply a linear gradient alternating transparent lines with colored ones, you can simply us "transparent" like this :

```css
background: repeating-linear-gradient(
    -45deg,
    transparent,
    transparent 10px,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 0,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 20px
);
```